# не встаёт фокус на контрол TextEdit от DevExpress15.2

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Есть простая форма редактирования с одним полем ввода `TextEdit` и 2 кнопками `Button`(подтвердить/отменить); при запуске формы хотелось бы получить фокус в поле ввода `TextEdit`и выделение его содержимого (для быстрой замены с клавиатуры, без выделения вручную) путём предварительного задания свойств `IsEnabled="True" Focusable="True" SelectAllOnGotFocus="True"`
и пытаюсь выставить фокус в коде C#:

```
var focus = textEdit.Focus();//фокус на контролл -- как показала отладка, вернёт false сразу же
textEdit.SelectAll();//дополнительно, выбрать всё содержимое принудительно
```

и почему-то ничего из этого не сработает: фокус не встаёт на `TextEdit`, выделение никаким образом не происходит, даже принудительно (а значение там есть, как минимум 0 по умолчанию)  :(
сброс/задание свойства `IsDefault` кнопки `Button` не влияют на отсутствие ожидаемого фокуса/выделения в `TextEdit`.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Layout:LayoutControl Layout:DockLayoutControl.Dock="Client" Padding="0" dxe:ValidationService.IsValidationContainer="True"  Name="validateContainer">
        <Layout:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpace="10" View="GroupBox" Header="{Binding NameGroup}"  
                        Name="GroupMain" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupMainHeader}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Layout:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
                <dxe:TextEdit
                    Name="textEdit"
                    Validate="TextEdit_Validate"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                    InvalidValueBehavior="AllowLeaveEditor"  
                    MaskType="Numeric"
                    MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="False" 
                    MaskSaveLiteral="False"
                    MaskBeepOnError="True"
                    IsEnabled="True" Focusable="True"  SelectAllOnGotFocus="True"  AllowSpinOnMouseWheel="False"
                    />                        
            </Layout:LayoutGroup>
            <Layout:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnEnter"  Click="BtnEnterClick"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsDefault="True" >
                </Button>
                <Button Name="btnClose" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="BtnCloseClick" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </Button>
            </Layout:LayoutGroup>

        </Layout:LayoutGroup>
    </Layout:LayoutControl>
</Grid>
```

Как заставить `TextEdit` выделять текст в своём содержимом ?

Comment: вы фокус выставляете в какой момент? Контрол этот уже прорисован?

Comment: @tym32167 в самом конце конструктора класса, после `InitializeComponent();` и заполнения всеми данными

Comment: попробуйте вызвать это после загрузки контрола, на событие типа Loaded

Comment: @tym32167  на `textEdit_Loaded()` отчасти заработало: фокус по-прежнему не появляется (соответственно нет и автовыделения) , но заработало принудительное выделение `textEdit.SelectAll();` -- в принципе мне этого достаточно, спс :)

Comment: пожалуйста, хорошо, что хоть что то завелось :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужно задать FocusBehavior для вашего контрола

```
<TextBox Text="This control is focused on startup">
    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <dxmvvm:FocusBehavior/>
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

подробнее можете почитать в [документации](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/17370/MVVM-Framework/Behaviors/Predefined-Set/FocusBehavior)

Comment: мне уже неактуально :( но всё равно спасибо, наверное.